# Local group policy logon startup script not executing

Tags: windows-7, script, boot, group-policy

This is for Windows 7

I have a .bat and .vbs file in a folder. The .bat runs the .vbs script. In the Local Policy Group editor, under Windows Settings/Scripts I added a reference to the .bat file in the Startup properties.

It seems as if my script is not running (I don’t see the result). Is there a log I can check to see why my script is not running? Do the .vbs and/or bat need to be in a special folder or anything? The .bat references the .vbs with a relative path - is that OK when being run as a startup script? Everything works fine when I just double-click to run the .bat file manually.

Comment: Are you running this script on your own box? A while ago during the course of regular development at work I changed the default file handler for .vbs files from the normal scripting host to notepad++ so I could edit them. Upon the next login, I was greeted by all of our domain's scripts popping up in notepad++. Lesson learned: make sure you aren't making any assumptions about the file associations for your .bat and .vbs scripts. Just a thought.

Comment: Why overcomplicate things with a BAT and a VBS.  Do everything in the VBS.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that my .bat files works, even though it's on by D:\scripts folder.  May I suggest put a simple command such as 'Notepad' in the batch file, just to see if it works.

May I also suggest that fire up Task Manager to see what process are are active, for example with your original script, are there any .vbs entries amongst the processes?

One more thought, are you configuring the scripts under **User** Configuration\Windows Settings\Scripts(Logon\Logoff) (my preference), or under Computer Configuration, which can be tricky.

Comment: I had them under Computer Configuration. I will try makinga  simple case just to confirm it is running. It is not a long running process so its hard to see it in task man

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a common error.

When you have a bat or powershell file, you need to move the script into the folder that you get when you click the "SHOW FILES", by moving the scripts there you are pretty sure that the system has all the required permissions to run at startup.

In my case it is: `C:\WINDOWS\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Startup`

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that the policy is applied by runnin rsop from command prompt on the computer.

Second of all make sure that the script is accessible from a shared folder that the policy would read from it.

Not to mention some policies requires a restart even after a gpupdate /force . If it's placed under user configuration and you're applying it on a OU of computers make sure loopback processing mode is set to merged.

What I suspect that there's an issue with the batch file calling the vbs file I would recommend the following:

Run a command prompt and try to call the file manually one time from elevated cmd and another time from  normal cmd, and it really depends on the methods you're trying to call the vbs file with either it is cscript or wscript now not to mention that some of those batch files are best to be configured as logon scripts under user settings and not computer (which I prefer).

Now try to edit the batch file that calls the script by the following :

```
@echo off

%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe

cscript script.vbs or \\path\script.vbs
```

I think it's better to store the script in the Sysvol share. Or you can simply add the vbs script into the login script. Also if you paste the content of the batch file it would be easier to diagnose what's going on.